# How to convert videos to 3D format so that I can watch them with 3D glasses

Tags: windows-7, video, software-rec, processing, 3d-multimedia

Are there any softwares to convert 2D videos to 3D (preferably XviD) so that I can watch them with 3D glasses? No matter if it's freeware or shareware.

Comment: This seems like asking for a headache. Even big budget movie studios have a difficult time converting a 2D film to 3D (Clash of the Titans).

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how that is possible.

Comment: I'm not expecting a full & real 3D output, of course. At least there may be some simulation-based results to give 3D feeling to some extent.

Comment: I don't think that's how that works, sorry :) Any 'simulated' effects would probably leave you feeling nauseous.

Comment: 2d in, 3d out? mhhh .. good luck with that :)

Comment: @akira: Actually, I found a software which claims to do that. :) Let's see if I'm lucky...

Comment: Weeeelll... If there were only 2 dimensions recorded in the first place the only thing you can do is simulate a third dimension (as you proposed). But I can't imagine that will do any good. It's like restoring a brudally compressed Image. Information that's gone (or has never been there) can't be restored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across a software named Tridef while searching for my question. I'll try it and see what happens...

> [**TriDef 3D**](http://www.tridef.com/home.html)
>
> - Play movies and photo slideshows in 3D
> - Watch 2D DVDs in 3D
> - Play games in 3D
> - View computer graphics on 3D displays

IMO, TriDef is very successful. I watched an XviD and very impressed about the result.

Besides, I found this [article](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/34245_how-to-convert-2d-videos-into-3d-an-easy-inexpensive-technique) titled "*How to convert 2d videos into 3d - An easy, inexpensive technique*" which seems useful.

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate 3D by showing the current "frame" to one eye and the previous "frame" to the other. It might actually be from a couple of frames ago, but the effect is the same.

This works given that the parallax on object nearer to the viewpoint/camera is greater than for objects further away.

However, this only work if the objects or camera are in constant uniform motion. When the camera or motion stops so does the 3D effect.

There is software to to this - but it's unlikely to be either freeware or shareware (but I'm willing to be proved wrong).

@zildjohn01's comment about it making you feel nauseous is probably correct ;)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any way to convert 2D MPEG videos into a 3D format in any realistic way. However if you have an Nvidia GeForce video card in your PC, then you can watch 3D formatted films (they have some 3D videos on their website) and play a lot of popular games in 3D.

If you look in your Nvidia control panel app, you probably have a heading that says "Enable Stereoscopic 3D" you can set this to use either normal cheap red/blue 3D glasses aka "[3D Vision Discover"](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3D_Vision_Discover_Main.html) ([setup instructions](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3D_Vision_Discover_driver_setup.html)), or you can buy "3D Vision wireless active shutter glasses" that give 3D stereo vision without any colour distortion if you have a 120Hz display ([check if you have here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3D_Vision_Requirements.html)). If you don't have this in your setup at the moment, the 3D drivers are a free download from Nvidia's website.

Whilst this isn't quite the same as the 3D TV technology, it's amazing how few people realise that their PC can quite often do this out of the box! [Nvidia have some example movies that use their 3D technology here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/3D_Vision_3D_Movies.html). Youtube also has a number of stereoscopic 3D videos in their [3D video showcase](http://www.youtube.com/user/3D), you can switch between different 3D types and test it out there.

Comment: Useful info. +1

Comment: It's worth stressing that this is only for games or films that are already in 3D. Games work by setting up two viewpoints/cameras (one for each eye) which can be done when the game is played. Though it won't necessarily apply to the cut scenes.

Answer (score 1):

"You can simulate 3D by showing the current "frame" to one eye and the previous "frame" to the other. It might actually be from a couple of frames ago, but the effect is the same." is right, but it is important to know that the "right" eye is dependent on the direction of the movement - if there is for example a dolphin in the foreground and it moves to the right then the "next" frame will be used for the left eye (so the previous one for the right eye) - and vice versa. You may try to use [3D 3DJournal software](http://www.3djournal.com) - they have a free version two (and the paid one is something about 25 bucks).

Comment: They have a [video guide how to create a 3D movie as well](http://www.3djournal.com/001/artic55.php)

Answer (score 1):

Corel VideoStudio x4 will convert your 2D into 3D.
Works great I converted a few videos and llok good.
You can download a full working version for 30 days

http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/eu/en/Product/1175714228541#tabview=tab0